# Динамическое редактирование ячеек таблицы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью JS можно сделать динамическое редактирование ячеек HTML таблицы?

Суть в чем, данные в таблицу заполняются из БД, и мне бы хотелось сделать так, что бы не заходя в БД я мог редактировать ячейки (которые записывались в БД). Ну знаете, как при работе с phpMyAdmin, 2 раза кликаешь на ячейку, редактируешь значения, затем жмешь Enter или в любом другом месте и все сохраняется.

Answer (score 0):

ajax.

1. Вешаете обработчик blur события на елемент
2. Добавляете данные
3. Сработало событие - аяксом передаёте данные на сервер
4. На сервере сохраняете

Comment: а как передавать даные на сервер, есть примеры? Или еще лучше, подскажите пожалуйста каким должен быть обработчик php для сохранения контента ячеек в БД

Comment: с php я перегнул. Вы отправляете данные на сервер. Сервер работает на любом нужном вам ЯП. Передача данны - гуглите jquery ajax. Серверный обработчик - скрипт, который принимает запрос, записывает в бд. Это базовые вещи, я могу вам подсказать только направление. Код пишите сами

Comment: окей, подскажите тогда направления к развязке по поводу БД, я раньше работал но немогу понять как записать для нужной ячейки

Comment: откройте любой курс(урок) по вашему ЯП + бд, например php mysql